# What do you call a male “charwoman”?

Tags: gender-politics

What is the male counterpart of a *charwoman* called?

Comment: [Charwoman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charwoman) is very dated. Nowadays regardless of their sex you can call a person who cleans offices, a *cleaner* or a [janitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janitor).

Comment: There is no such word: men were not employed as part-time cleaners during the age in which charwomen were.

Comment: The word is just _Charman_ http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charman also from OED _char-boy_, _chargirl_, _charlady_, _charmaid_ and _char-folk_ if you want to avoid gender completely.

Comment: OED lists *char* as colloquial shortening of *charwoman,* which seems to remove any sex-specificity. In Academe we are now long accustomed to the unsexed designation *chair* for department head.

Comment: *Charman* is exceptionally rare, rarer than *charwoman* is today. Are you looking for an equivalent up-dated term, which I'd suggest is a **cleaner** or the male equivalent of *charwoman* ? If it is the latter, I don't see where the problem lies, and I would consider closing this question for lack of research.

Comment: @tchrist They had man-servants at schools and universities etc.: so terms like "scout" (Oxford), "gyp" or "bedder" (Cambridge), "sweater" (Winchester), etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
What I was interested in knowing is - is there an official gender antonym for 'charwoman'. I know the term is rarely used; still it'd be good to know.

Comment: I voted to reopen on the basis that the Merriam-Webster entry for _charman_ is not always available without subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this question is effectively *general reference* due to the obvious male version of *charwoman* being ***charman*** which can be found in the Merriam-Webster online dictionary at http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charman it appears that that word/page is not always available without a subscription to the Unabridged version, so I've decided to add an answer anyway.

> Merriam-Webster
> **charman** noun (origin *chare + man*)
> *plural* **charmen**
> a man who does janitor's odd jobs

As early as 1779 or thereabouts in his own *Dissertations on the English Language* Webster notes that *char-woman* and *char-man* may have been used in New England but could well be 'on the way out'.

> CHORE, a corruption of *char* is an English word, still used in many parts of England, as a *char-man*, a *char-woman*; but in America, it is perhaps confined to New England. It signifies small domestic jobs of work, and it's place cannot be supplied by any other single word in the language.
>
> THESE local words, and others of less note, are gradually growing into disuse, and will probably be lost : Except such as are necessary in some particular occupation
> [Archive.org](https://ia801408.us.archive.org/9/items/dissertationsone00webs/dissertationsone00webs.pdf) page 112(118)

By 1832 Webster pretty much seals the fate of *char-woman* in American English.
The M-W 1928 unabridged version (which is exactly as the 1832 publication) gives

> **char-woman**, n. A woman hired for odd work, or for single days.
> [Char-man and Char-woman are, I believe, not used in America.]

---

Meanwhile, in the UK, *char-xxxx* was still very much in use.

OED has examples of many different forms of *char-xxxx* from 1661 to 1966 including the amusing *char-parson* (A parson who attended two churches) and the genderless *char-folk*.

> **char-**  comb.form
> [OED2] the first element of charwoman, used to form words designating persons who do cleaning work, etc., as char-boy, chargirl, charlady, charmaid, charman, etc.
>
> [OED online] **charman** *n.*
> 1888   *Pall Mall Gaz.* 10 Oct.    The Guards' Memorial is now given over to the charmen.
> 1895   *Macmillan's Mag.* July 201/1   The charmen (the men who sweep out the House of Commons).

*Charman* has probably never been a very common word, but *char-women* and *char-lady* much more so, reflecting the fact that it was much more common for women to do *char-work*.

In the 1963 comedy film *Ladies Who Do*, written by Michael Pertwee (brother of Jon Pertwee of Doctor Who fame), a group of *char-ladies* find a hot stock market tip in a waste basket and make a large sum of money.
Well worth watching.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a term to exclusively refer to male servants, then **valet** is the closest word. However *valet* is the counterpart of a lady's maid, who is [not expected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady%27s_maid) to do chores like dusting or sweeping. In contrast, a charwoman is supposed to do any odd chore in the house.

Comment: And these days, of course, most valets do nothing of the sort, either: they park cars.